# How to display print dialog in java fx and print node

Tags: javafx

I'd like to show a dialog prior to printing so that users can choose their preferred printer and also change page setup if possible,
I'm using Java 8 update 31 in a desktop environment (Windows 8 64 bit), my current code like this

```
Node node = new Circle(100, 200, 200);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null) {
boolean success = job.printPage(node);
if (success) {
    job.endJob();
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [showPrintDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html#showPrintDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) method of PrinterJob.

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())){
    boolean success = job.printPage(node);
    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to resize node if its too big? (cropped on actual printing page). Changing its width and height makes some content not visible if it has a lot of it.